# Add random values from Array1 to Array2 until a condition is met

Tags: javascript

Two arrays: 
1 - userInput contains character string entered by a user via prompt(). Can contain anywhere from 1 to 61 characters.
2 - letterArray is static and contains 9 characters.

I created a variable arrayCount to find the length of userArray. I need to create an if/else statement that will append a random character from letterArray to the end of userInput until arrayCount is equal to 61, at which point I can carry on with the execution of the rest of the function (which is working for me).

I know just enough javascript to know what is possible but with only a vague idea how to accomplish it. My attempts so far have been futile.

I've tried .push but I'm pretty sure my syntax is way off. Have been searching the internet for a couple hours with most of my answers gleaned from w3schools.com.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
function chartFunction() {
    var formInput = prompt("Please enter your phrase", "This eye chart is absolutely fantastic");
    var capsInput = formInput.toUpperCase();
    var userInput = capsInput.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var letterArray = ["E", "F", "Z", "K", "L", "O", "I", "D"]
    var rand1 = letterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArray.length)];
    var arrayCount = userInput.length

    if(arrayCount !== 61) {
        userInput.push(letterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArray.length)]);
    } else {

    document.write("<p>");
    document.write(userInput[0]);
    document.write("<p>");
        document.write(userInput[1],userInput[2]);
```

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you update your question with the code you've tried and an example of the input and expected output

Comment: in your code `userInput` is not an `Array` so, `.push` wont work and `userInput` is defined twice which is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying to use `.push` on a `string`. With your problem description, I came up with the following solution, let me know if I'm missing something.

```js
function chartFunction() {
  const MAX_CHAR = 61;
  
  let userInput = prompt("Please enter your phrase", "This eye chart is absolutely fantastic");
  
  // replace space and convert to uppercase
  userInput = userInput.replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase();

  if (userInput.length < MAX_CHAR) {
    const letterArray = ["E", "F", "Z", "K", "L", "O", "I", "D"];
    const numberOfCharsToGenerate = MAX_CHAR - userInput.length;
    
    /*
      Array(numberOfCharsToGenerate) => generates an empty array set with the length specified
      
      .fill('') => fill the empty array set with an empty string, which makes the actual array with value(here value is '')
      .map() => modifies the array with the random string
      .join() => converts array to string with delimiter ''
    */

    userInput = userInput + Array(numberOfCharsToGenerate).fill('')
      .map(() => letterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArray.length)]).join('');
  }

  // printing final 'userInput' and its length
  console.log(userInput, userInput.length);
  
  // remaining logic here
}

chartFunction();
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you thank you! Did you convert the string to an array with: userInput = userInput + Array(numberOfCharsToGenerate).fill('') ?

Comment: `Array(numberOfCharsToGenerate)` will just generate a empty array set. `.fill('')` will fill the array with empty string. Updated the code with comments